# editar ip desde browser

Tags: php

Esto creando una web de monitoreo de equipos, pero me causo una duda.

Si tengo un equipo con una ip ejemplo 127.0.0.1, pero al tiempo esta ip cambia y la quiero modificar directo del browser se puede? si es asi cual seria la manera de realizarlo, dejo una imagen para orientarlos mejor.
[image: website]

Comment: Te recomiendo que aclares un poco tu pregunta , tambien agregar un poco de codigo para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos tu entras a google.com que tiene por ejemplo su servidor xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx y cuando acedes se tre cambia a yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy es otra direccion.

Extrapolando, te doy una direccion y te digo es en madrid y cuando llegas alli te digo ; No esta dkreccion ha cambiado es en barcelona.

Asi suena tu pregunta.

Si lo que quieres es redireccionar un dominio a una ip diferente con nuevas DNS eso ya es otra cosa diferente.